# Getting a Type Error when using Pandas "where" function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set where a column is called "YearMade" which is of type int64. I am trying to replace the values in the "YearMade" Column where any values that is less than equal to 1918 is replaced by the median of the column. So I try:

`df.where(df['YearMade'] > 1918, df['YearMade'].median(), inplace = True)`

However, I get a type error. What is wrong that I am doing here ? And, how to correct it? See error message below:

````
<ipython-input-83-b202aa389b1d> in <module>
      1 # We replace all the rows before 1929 with the median
      2 
----> 3 df.where(df['YearMade'] > 1918, df['YearMade'].median(), inplace = True)
      4 df['YearMade'].describe()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors, try_cast)
   9274         other = com.apply_if_callable(other, self)
   9275         return self._where(
-> 9276             cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors=errors, try_cast=try_cast
   9277         )
   9278 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors, try_cast)
   9103             # reconstruct the block manager
   9104 
-> 9105             self._check_inplace_setting(other)
   9106             new_data = self._data.putmask(
   9107                 mask=cond,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _check_inplace_setting(self, value)
   5303 
   5304                 raise TypeError(
-> 5305                     "Cannot do inplace boolean setting on "
   5306                     "mixed-types with a non np.nan value"
   5307                 )

TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to replace the values only for the specific column. I think you are getting the error because the where condition is applied to all columns which have mixed dtypes.
Try this:

```
df['YearMade'].where(df['YearMade'] > 1918, df['YearMade'].median(), inplace = True)
```